# Netcat fails to start in listening mode

Tags: linux, centos, tcp, netcat

I'm using CentOS 6.7 (Final) system, and when I try to run `nc` in listening mode it prints the following:

```bash
nc -l 1234
nc: Protocol not available
```

The port is not bound. I tried other port numbers too.
This bug seem to have been reported already: https://access.redhat.com/solutions/1753753. Unfortunately it is not very detailed.

Package information:

```yaml
Name        : nc
Arch        : x86_64
Version     : 1.84
Release     : 24.el6
```

Is there something else I need to try out?

Comment: Which version of nc are you using?

Comment: @JennyD I updated the post, please check out

Comment: Unfortunately the only fix is a downgrade, as described below. I'm also voting to move this question to [unix.se] since it's not strictly about systems administration. It's a good site with some experts who leave me in awe, so please don't think the close vote is because your question is bad or anything.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I ran into the same issue. You can solve it this way:

```bash
# Removes the old package
yum erase nc
    
# Manually downloads the working package from the Official Repository
wget http://vault.centos.org/6.6/os/x86_64/Packages/nc-1.84-22.el6.x86_64.rpm

# Installs the package
rpm -iUv nc-1.84-22.el6.x86_64.rpm
```

Please note that the package is for `x86_64` (64-bit). If you need `i386` (32-bit), the correct one is:

```bash
wget http://vault.centos.org/6.6/os/i386/Packages/nc-1.84-22.el6.i686.rpm
```

Comment: Using rpm with the -i and -U flags simultaneously looks weird (but works). More standard invocation is -ivh or -Uvh.

Comment: work like a charm!

Comment: This path no longer works

Comment: @BradLaney why doesn't?

Comment: @EddieC. The URL was 404ing for me when I made the comment. It appears to be working now. Nevermind.

Comment: @BradLaney Ah, ok :).

Comment: you can also find it here http://www.rpm-find.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=nc%28x86-64%29

Comment: It worked like a charm twice!

Answer (score 11):

This particular version of netcat has a bug. Until there's a fix out for it, the only thing you can do is to downgrade to a previous version - `sudo yum remove nc-1.84-24.el6.x86_64; sudo yum install nc-1.84-22.el6.x86_64` should do the trick.

Comment: Doesn't `yum` have an argument which can downgrade to a specific version of a package without first uninstalling?

Comment: Great, but I was unable to downgrade. Yum says no package available (both the `install` with specific version and the `downgrade` command). Also tried searching for that rpm file and hasn't found yet.

Answer (score 4):

Replying the question:

1. YES, downgrade is needed so that nc can listen.
   and as for the other comments:

a) -p is not supposed to be used when in listening mode. from nc manpage:

> -l      Used to specify that nc should listen for an incoming connection rather than initiate
>               a connection to a remote host.  It is an error to use this option in conjunction with
>                the -p, -s, or -z options.

b) downgrade can be done in one step, yum downgrade command works with the url to the package:

```
$ rpm -q nc
nc-1.84-24.el6.x86_64
$ nc -l 12345 #Although the syntax is correct, the command fails
nc: Protocol not available
$ nc -l -p 12345 #attempt to run with incorrect syntax
usage: nc [-46DdhklnrStUuvzC] [-i interval] [-p source_port]
          [-s source_ip_address] [-T ToS] [-w timeout] [-X proxy_version]
          [-x proxy_address[:port]] [hostname] [port[s]]
$ sudo yum downgrade http://vault.centos.org/6.6/os/x86_64/Packages/nc-1.84-22.el6.x86_64.rpm  #shortcut to downgrade
...
Setting up Downgrade Process
nc-1.84-22.el6.x86_64.rpm                                                              |  57 kB     00:00
Examining /var/tmp/yum-root-Iq4yc7/nc-1.84-22.el6.x86_64.rpm: nc-1.84-22.el6.x86_64
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package nc.x86_64 0:1.84-22.el6 will be a downgrade
---> Package nc.x86_64 0:1.84-24.el6 will be erased
--> Finished Dependency Resolution

Dependencies Resolved

==============================================================================================================
 Package          Arch                 Version                     Repository                            Size
==============================================================================================================
Downgrading:
 nc               x86_64               1.84-22.el6                 /nc-1.84-22.el6.x86_64               109 k

Transaction Summary
==============================================================================================================
Downgrade     1 Package(s)

Total size: 109 k
Is this ok [y/N]: y
...
Removed:
  nc.x86_64 0:1.84-24.el6

Installed:
  nc.x86_64 0:1.84-22.el6

Complete!
$ nc -l -p 12345 #attempt to run with incorrect syntax
usage: nc [-46DdhklnrStUuvzC] [-i interval] [-p source_port]
          [-s source_ip_address] [-T ToS] [-w timeout] [-X proxy_version]
          [-x proxy_address[:port]] [hostname] [port[s]]
$ nc -l 12345 # try to listen again
^C
$#nc successully opens a socket on 12345. had to stop it with ctrl+C
```

Answer (score 1):

```
# nc -l -p 1234
```

You can listen on that port by explicitely using `-p` flag:

```
-p source_port
         Specifies the source port nc should use, subject to privilege restrictions and availability.
```

The problem was along the lines of `nc` treating 1234 as the *destination* port (despite being run in listening mode), and trying to listen on port 0 (which produced that weird message). Explicitely passing `-p` works around it.

Comment: I tried this on centos 6 and it didn't work using the version   nc-1.84-24
The fix was to downgrade to the version nc-1.84-22  as per the accepted answer.

Comment: that version does not allow using -p with -l.

Answer (score -2):

install nmap:

> yum install nmap

try:

> ncat -l 1234

Comment: Please read the question and the already supplied answers to learn why your answer isn't sufficient in that particular case.

Comment: Upvoting as this helped me.  While @Ronald perhaps did not directly address the OP's concern of getting netcat itself to work, using nmap's ncat tool works the same for at least my use case where my environment did not allow me to downgrade netcat as the popular solution suggests.  At the end of the day, I had a tool that allowed me to run a listening tool on a specific port so I could continue on with my project.